# How to pass a string value to ReportViewer on another server

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Is it possible to pass a value from the program to a ReportViewer report located on a different server? The value cannot be used as a parameter that accepts data. The purpose of this value is to use it to access other data from the database and this value is not stored in the Database. 
For example, I want to pass the name of the supervisor who created the schedule to ReportViewer and then use that name to select additional data from other tables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. It sounds like you're trying to pass data to a report without passing it as a parameter, to be used to pull data from a database that doesn't actually use that particular piece of data?

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I'm new to posting. Yes, you are correct in that I am trying to pass data to a report without passing it as a parameter, to be used to pull data (such as name, title and ID) from a database  and concatenate the 3 fields into one. Is there a way to do that?